# Delete a number bullets that don't have content

Tags: vba, ms-word

I ran into a strange problem when trying to delete bullets that don't have anything there.

To achieve this I started to try to come up with a code that announces the number of the bullet that has no content.

My issue: how to check for no content in a given paragraph.

When I use the following lines of code:

```
Sub Announcer()
Dim DocPara As Paragraph

For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

  If DocPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering Then
  If DocPara.Range.Text = "" Then

  MsgBox DocPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString

  End If
  End If

Next
```

It does not pop the msgbox because DocPara.Range.Text does not evaluate in "" (empty string) but rather in " (the double quotes).

Here is an [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3epc9o4yoc9spaf/Problem.bmp?dl=0) of the debugging and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/po1o6ntv7jrwcg4/Delete%20Numbered%20Bullets.docm?dl=0) is my test file.

I struggle to understand the cause for this and I struggle more to get a solution. I have tried doing DocPara.Range.Text = chr(34) to no avail...

Do you by chance have any suggestions?

Comment: `Chr(34) ` is `"`, so there's no reason to compare it to your supposedly empty string. But if you were to compare it to `Chr(13)` (carriage return) then your code would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I just changed the code to check if:

```
If Len(DocPara.Range.Text) = 1 then
```

instead... so for my purposes now it works.

EDIT:
As suggested by Uri, the initial code works if compared with Chr(13)  (carriage return) works!

Thanks everyone,

Maxi

Comment: That works, and is generally the best approach. Every paragraph contains the "paragraph mark" - ANSI character 13. So an "empty" paragraph always has a length of 1. You might want to include this information in your answer for the sake of completeness. Here's a similar question, FWIW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317024/deleting-empty-paragraphs-in-word-using-vba-not-all-empty-paragraphs-deleted

Comment: `Chr(13)` is not a "paragraph mark", and it has nothing to do with Word specifically. When hitting the `Enter` key, two characters hits are recorded the "line break" (`=Chr(10)`) and the "carriage return" (`=Chr(13)`). To be on the safe side, the two characters should be stripped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are white spaces.
First lets define a `Strip` function to remove white spaces, inspired by python's [strip](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html).

```
Function Strip(ByVal s As String) As String
    Strip = Trim(Replace(Replace(s, Chr(13), " "), Chr(10), " "))
End Function
```

Then we will replace

```
If DocPara.Range.Text = "" Then
```

With

```
If Strip(DocPara.Range.Text) = "" Then
```